# PHP using strpos for checking for form specific word?

Tags: php, validation, strpos

i'm trying to use strpos or some sort of method to search for the word 'validated' within a textarea known as $likes and it'll return an error if not found. I wasn't sure how to get around validating two conditions (the textfield 'likes' cannot be empty and it must contain the word 'validation') so I kind of threw another if statement which didn't work and now I am desperately plugging it into my html..

Here's my basic php validation, I removed all my other error handling and left the textarea one.

```
   <?php
        // define variables + initialize
        $nameErr = $likesErr = $placesErr = $thingsErr = $emaiLErr = $shopErr = $emailyesErr= "";
        $name = $likes = $places = $email = $emailyes = $shops = $things = "";
        $shops = array();
        $things = array();
        $likesErr2 = "Your likes must include the word 'validated'!";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        //textarea likes
        if (empty($_POST["likes"])) {
            $likesErr = "Please tell me what you like about hiking! :(";
        }

        else {
            $likes = $_POST["likes"];
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Here is my attempted us at strpos: :(

```
 <label>What do you like about hiking?</label><span class = "error">* <?php echo $likesErr;?></span><br>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" input type="text" id="likes" name="likes">
 <?php echo $likesErr2 (if ((strpos($likes, "validated") === false)?></textarea>
```

My current setup is resulting in a 500 error so I feel like I'm definetly doing something wrong with the php.

### **EDIT**

I have updated my php to this:

```
//textfield likes
if (empty($_POST["likes"])) {
    $likesErr = "Please tell me what you like about hiking! :(";
}
else if ((strpos($likes, "validated") === false){
    $likesErr2 = "Please include the word 'validated' in your likes textarea!";
}

else {
    $likes = $_POST["likes"];
}
```

and html portion

```
        <div>
            <br><br>        
            <label>What do you like about hiking?</label><span class = "error">* <?php echo $likesErr; echo $placesErr2;?></span><br>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="likes" name="likes"></textarea>

            <br><br>
        </div>
```

And I'm still getting a 500 error ):

Comment: `<textarea>` does not hold the `input type="text"` attribute.

Comment: Oops! I'll get rid of that.

Comment: If code above is complete, the `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` remains opened (add a curly bracket at the end)

Comment: as stated above ^ you have a missing closing `}` brace and that would cause your 500 error, unexpected end of file notice. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: in your last line apart from it being a weird command you open 4 brackets and close only two. And no ; after echo. Your if command with strpos looks like "if validate is not present print the closing textarea tag"

Comment: Sorry my code isn't complete on here, I have the closing bracket in my document } i'll edit the sample code here.

Comment: `((strpos($likes, "validated") === false)` : 3 brackets opened, 2 closed. If you have access to apache logs, check-it for more detailed info about 500 errors

Comment: I got it to work! what a silly mistake,  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example use of strpos:

```
<?php
$str = 'Time spent with cats is never wasted.';

if (strpos($str, 'dog') === FALSE) {
    echo 'no dog';
}

echo (strpos($str, 'dog') === FALSE) ? 'no dog' : 'hot dog!';

// Outputs: 'no dogno dog'
```